# How can I restrict user input when the value inputed is greater than a certain value Swift 5.1

Tags: swift

My current code is:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.transferBalanceTextField {
       if transferBalanceTextField.text! > currentBalance.text! {
          return false
       }
    }
    return true
}
```

But there are issues with this because if I type in a 6 first and the currentBalance is 582, it doesn't let me type in another digit because it believes the 6 is greater then 582, HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to Ints in your case, and check it:

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.transferBalanceTextField {
        if let str1 = transferBalanceTextField.text,
           let int1 = Int(str1),
           let str2 = currentBalance.text, 
           let int2 = Int(str2), 
           int1 > int2 {
             return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Avoid force unwrap as much as possible - it'll help you a lot when code will be big.

**UPDATE after comments**

Simple code above only shows converting Strings to Ints and testing it. I thought it's clear, you see it and understand.

So - if you want full test according to your case - you have also take into account what exactly this function check (*should* in its name) and how to deal with it.

You have two states of your field - current and next one after possible update (should you change the text in field on user input or not?). Above simple code only test current state *before* new user input. You have to do checking with future possible text value when new user input already *accepted* to the field.

For example how it work now using code above (lets user already input 100 in first field and have 500 in another field):

- user press "0" - want to enter 1000
- you got call of this method
- you check *old* value - 100 - against another value and decide should it be updated or not
- method return true - (should change)
- and it change it - field become 1000
- after it you can't update field - method now will always return false (1000 is over 500)

What you need to do:

- create string what should be in field after user input (in my example it must be 1000) - you have current value + new input + range on this new input
- and check against it and another value.

Why it's matter - in this method you can check all cases of user input - simple input one char by one, paste from clipboard, replacing some characters, input in middle of string, full clear and so on - and all this must be done without and before real field visual updating.

Here is full code, you should use for full your case:

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.loginField {
        if let str1 = loginField.text,
           let str2 = passwordField.text,
           let rangeExpr = Range(range, in: str1) {
            let strFuture = str1.replacingCharacters(in: rangeExpr, with: string)
            if let int1 = Int(strFuture),
               let int2 = Int(str2),
               int1 > int2 {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

main change is in line

```swift
let strFuture = str1.replacingCharacters(in: rangeExpr, with: string)
```

Please, read methods you use, how it's work, and what your should do for it carefully - and you will get your progress much faster.

Comment: You can also use if conditions with if let by comma operator

Comment: I replaced my old shouldChangeCharactersIn range code with this but didn't work still...

Comment: I updated my comment, please take a look at it.

Comment: It still doesn't helped you?